# Suppress all output in yum except for errors

Tags: package-management, yum, error-handling

In `yum` when you do an update with `yum update` you normally get all *success* and *error* messages output on the CLI.

Is there any way to have `yum` suppress all successful package installations and only print out when there was an error installing a package?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
yum update -q -y
```

The `-q` is quiet mode.

The `-y` assumes yes to everything.

This still prints errors.

Comment: I'm not really sure why, but `yum update -yq` doesn't work for me. The `-y` and `-q` have to be separate, like they are in the example.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would probably be to redirect message output.

You can redirect standard message output to send non-error messages to /dev/null (aka not print them).  For this, you must automatically accept updates, otherwise it will appear to stall.

```
yum -y update 1> /dev/null
```

This still prints error messages.  If you want to send the error messages to a file, you can append `2>> [file]` to the command to make the total command:

```
yum -y update 1> /dev/null 2>> [file]
```

Note:  `2>>` appends the output to a file, and `2>` replaces the file.